# error CS0234: Имя типа или пространства имен "Management" отсутствует в пространстве имен "System"

Tags: c#

Добрый вечер
Сделан билдер, в ресурсы помещен файл, при компиляции которого, возникает ошибка выше, ссылка указана, но он её как будто не видит. 
В [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А на свежем проекте воспроизводится?

Comment: В свежем .NET для этого нужен nuget-пакет https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/

Answer (score 0):

Скорее все нужна ссылка на dll. Нажми правой кнопкой по "Ссылки" и выбери "Добавить ссылки". Слева выбери категорию "Сборки" и выбери System.Managment

Comment: Я это уже делал, видите, справа выделил, если просто вписать ссылку через using - оно не добавляется. Только так, как вы написали. Но я и пробовал через Dll Import, никак

Comment: Да, но пространство имен может быть разбито на несколько dll. Поэтому часть у вас типа подключена, а часть в отдельной dll.